# Fragment not attached to a context after asynctask

Tags: android

Hello everyone I have a problem in fragment, I get a null pointer exception in fragment after changing from second to third fragment:On first onCreateView it's working fine, but when i change it, i get null pointer exception. I tryed with getContext(),getActivity(),requireContext() but I always get this exception. Thanks
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object   android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

```
 public class GetListaVozila extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void> {



        protected void onPreExecute() {
            /****** NOTE: You can call UI Element here. *****/
//            progressDialog = getDialogProgressBar().show();
//            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        }


        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... urls) {
            try {
                System.out.println("pozvanooo1");
                URL url = new URL("http://example/app/lista_vozila_novo.php");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpConn.setDoInput(true);
                httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("key", key);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                httpConn.connect();
                OutputStream os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
                parsedString = convertinputStreamToString(is);
                System.out.println("pozvanooo parsedstring" + parsedString + " - " + key);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<PozicijaVozila>>() {
            }.getType();
            listaVozila = gson.fromJson(parsedString, type);
            values = new ArrayList<String>();
//            ArrayList<PozicijaVozila> array_sort = new ArrayList<PozicijaVozila>(listaVozila);
            for (PozicijaVozila p : listaVozila) {
                values.add(p.getIme());
            }
            it = new ArrayList<PozicijaVozila>(listaVozila);
//            for (int i = 0; i < it.size(); i++) {
//                values.add(it.get(i).getIme());
//            }
I got exception here: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
            editTextNaziv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireContext());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.vozila_listview);
                    dialog.setTitle(requireContext().getResources().getString(R.string.izaberite_vozilo));
                    listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
                    dialog.show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                    listView.setItemChecked(selectedIndex, false);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            int itemPosition = position;
                            selectedIndex = position;
                            String itemValue = (String) listView
                                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
                            currentSelectedView = view;
                            editTextNaziv.setText(itemValue);
                            // Show Alert
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F8C304"));
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }

                    });


                }
            });
//            progressDialog.dismiss();
//            if (selectedIndex == 0 && values.size() > 0) {
//                editTextNaziv.setText(values.get(0));
//            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `getActivity()` is `null` when `AsyncTask` finishes its job. it is placed inside `Fragment`, so this means that this `Fragment` wasn't attached to any `Activity` at that particular moment (job end). you should cancel your `AsyncTask` in some of lifecycle methods like `onPause` or `onDestroyView` for avoiding this problem. but be awared that `AsyncTask` won't have a place to print result of its job (as `Fragment` - GUI side - was removed from screen). if you want to keep that work for some other `Fragment` or just for storing for future use - start and keep `AsyncTask` inside `Activity` (as you see it is tightened to it anyway by `getActivity()` method, not to `Fragment`)